# how to do html form vaildation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using html and jquery to do some form vaildations

for ex if user click on a field and doesn't enter any thing, than he clicks on different field... i want to turn field border to red. this way user will know that he can not skip this field...

also when user clicks on button submit, than i also want to do this same, if field is empty than turn border to red

below is what i have so far, is there a better way to do this? bbc it seem like i am repeating alot of same code

on up side it does work fine, so  guess i can just keep on repeating code

note i have like 20+ fields so jquery function will be long

- forgot to tell that i am using asp fields:

  ```
   <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameCTB"  ClientIDMode="Static" class="input form-control input-md" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  ```

javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {

             $('#FirstNameCTB').blur('input', function () {
                 if ($('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').val().trim() == '') 
                     $('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', 'red');
                 else
                     $('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', '');
             });
             $('#LastNameCTB').blur('input', function () {
                 if ($('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').val().trim() == '')
                     $('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', 'red');
                 else
                     $('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', '');
             });

             $('.CHECKOUTLBC').click(function () {
                 if ($('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').val().trim() == '') {
                     $('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', 'red');
                     return false; // dont go to server side 
                 } else {
                     $('#<%=FirstNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', '');
                 }
                 if ($('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').val().trim() == '') {
                     $('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', 'red');
                     return false; // dont go to server side 
                 } else {
                     $('#<%=LastNameCTB.ClientID%>').css('border-color', '');
                 }
             });
         });
         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryvalidation.org/ can be your solution.
Also here's the examples.
https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

This plugin has, red border, submit control etc.

Also this plugin will be good.

http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form

```js
  $.validate({
    modules : 'location, date, security, file',
    onModulesLoaded : function() {
      $('#country').suggestCountry();
    }
  });

  // Restrict presentation length
  $('#presentation').restrictLength( $('#pres-max-length') );
```

```html
<form action="" id="registration-form">
  <p>
    E-mail
    <input name="email" data-validation="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    User name
    <input name="user" data-validation="length alphanumeric" 
   data-validation-length="3-12" 
   data-validation-error-msg="User name has to be an alphanumeric value (3-12 chars)">
  </p>
  <p>
    Password
    <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="strength" 
   data-validation-strength="2">
  </p>
  <p>
    Repeat password
    <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation">
  </p>
  <p>
    Birth date
    <input name="birth" data-validation="birthdate" 
   data-validation-help="yyyy-mm-dd">
  </p>
  <p>
    Country
    <input name="country" id="country" data-validation="country">
  </p>
  <p>
    Profile image
    <input name="image" type="file" data-validation="mime size required" 
   data-validation-allowing="jpg, png" 
   data-validation-max-size="300kb" 
   data-validation-error-msg-required="No image selected">
  </p>
  <p>
    User Presentation (<span id="pres-max-length">100</span> characters left)
    <textarea name="presentation" id="presentation"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" data-validation="required" 
   data-validation-error-msg="You have to agree to our terms">
    I agree to the <a href="..." target="_blank">terms of service</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset form">
  </p>
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your form inputs are called input, you could loop through them and apply the function with something similar to this.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(n = 0; n < inputs.length; n++){
  $(function () {
    inputs[n].blur('input', function () {
      if (inputs[n].val().trim() == '') 
        inputs[n].css('border-color', 'red');
      else
        inputs[n].css('border-color', '');
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: can I use getelement by class rather than name?

Comment: Yes, just give your elements the desired class name then change inputs to = document.getElementsByClassName('desiredClassName')

Comment: thanks, i likt this solution but do you know why this prints 0? `var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
         alert(inputs.length);`

Comment: Because your inputs are called "form-control input-md" - change the name in between the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

couple things:

1. issue maybe be that javascript is beeing run before the controls
2. you should not mix core javascript with jquery libary
3. you do not need loop when using blur, on, click, etc jquery functions

keeping all those above things in mind, below is a better solutions. works for me

```
 $(function () {
     $(".input").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim() == '') 
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        else
            $(this).css('border-color', '');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this example below.

```html
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

[Have a look at this example:](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)